# Is it possible to position overlay div on a horizontal scrollable content with css - no JS

Tags: html, css

I have div with horizontal scrollable content. Trying to apply overlay for the entire content just using css. This scrollable content may keep growing. Is there a way to achieve this without javascript code.

```css
.bg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #888888;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="overlay">

</div>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
<img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

> Using the **overlay effect** by **[flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)**  instead of **[absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute).**

```
.overlay{
  white-space:nowrap;  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #888888;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

And add the images inside the overlay div

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <-- images here --->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.bg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.overlay{
  white-space:nowrap;  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #888888;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.images img{ white-space: normal;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
    <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @Pasupathi Rajamanickam? If any changes comment me. I would happy to change the answer too :). I hope this is working perfectly. btw thanks :).

Comment: This is good approach but I cannot add images inside overlay, because what I'm trying to achieve also is, I need the blur effect at right most side of it. So typically I'll add left: 90% to overlay.

Answer (score 0):

`position:sticky` can do it:

```css
.bg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.overlay {
  position: sticky;
  width:inherit;
  margin-right:-300px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: #888888;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">

  </div>
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi_0.png" class="bg" />
</div>
```